# Font style changing in CRM 2011 SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have created one report using SSRS 2008 and deployed it to CRM 2011(On-premise). When I run this report from Visual Studio 2010, it works fine as per the font style used(**Trebuchet MS**). But when I run the same report from CRM, the font is getting changed to '**Times New Roman**'. And I checked, '**Trebuchet MS**' is installed in server. Or do I need to install this font in CRM? If so, how can I install that?

Below is the image which shows the same report running  in (A) From Visual Studio and (B) From CRM 2011 but they are with different fonts. Can any one help me to get this report done with **Trebuchet MS** in CRM?

[image]

Comment: Have you tested from multiple machines?

Comment: font is installed also inside the server where SSRS is running?

Comment: Both SSRS and CRM resides on the same VMWare machine. BTW how can I see whether this font is installed in SSRS or not?

Comment: you can open wordpad and check if the font is available

Comment: Yes, that font is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a browser related issue. Have you tried to export to a PDF and see what the font is? It might help.

Comment: Its showing correct font in pdf or word. This problem is only in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the export shows the correct font then the problem is that some CSS on the page is overwriting what you have set for the report. Right click on the font then can you screenshot it in the browser (preferably chrome). This may let you know where it is picking up that font-family.

To overlay it use this

```
#whateveryouridis{ font-family: Trebuchet MS !important }
```